# psql : could not connect to server:

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, psql

I recently installed ubuntu and downloaded postgres from brew, but when trying to get into psql I get this error:

```
psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

I have tried alternative varias and without success, could anyone help

Comment: Have you initialized it with pg_ctl?

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: Did you create a database cluster? If you did, did you start it?

Comment: Did you have a look at the [many, many identical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+could+not+connect+to+server)

Comment: This is the top google result for "psql: error: could not connect to server: could not connect to server: No such file or directory". Would be nice if someone would have answered the question.